# Having trouble with class creation for a java dice game

Tags: java, class, constructor, implementation, dice

I Just started learning Java a few months back andI have been set a task to create a simple dice game in java. The first exercise is to implement a Die class, with the following instance variable, constructor and methods:

```
private int faceValue; // Current face value of die
private int sides; // Number of sides
private Random generator;
public Die(int s){}
public void throwDie(){}
public int getFaceValue(){}
public String toString() {}
```

in a card game i previously coded, i used:

```
public static final String suits[] = { "Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};
```

to set the values of my suits, would i be able to do the same thing to my "faceValue" variable, only setting them to 1,2,3,4,5 and 6?

thanks for reading, hoping someone on here can help, implementing classes and constructors is something i seem to be struggling on!

Comment: sorry what is the question?

Comment: You can, but its not a good idea. The core of your assignment is the use of the `Random` class. You should read its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Pay particular attention to the `nextInt(int)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a lot like a homework problem, so I won't give you an implementation, but an idea.  (If it's not, then say so and I can adjust accordingly.)

I think that the parameter that you pass to the constructor is probably supposed to be the number of sides in your Die, which means that the max number of sides is variable.  You wouldn't want to create an array or an enumeration on the fly, since I imagine the only face values you want are integral, and that's more work than is necessary.

You probably want to assign that input value to the variable which represents it, and use it to create a number generator that scales between 0 and that number.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're getting at. So I should just set my sides variable, to 6, (assuming i'm using a regular 6 sided dice), and leave the array out. You are right in that the only values I want for faceValue are intergral. You are also right in that it is a homework problem, and so I was just looking for a point in the right direction, thank you!